# Jupyter notebook : when i open an exist or create a new .ipynb file, show me an error: "500 : invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter notebook in my raspberry pi 4 , and it works.
but after i installed some other package, the jupyter notebook can't open ipynb file (shows : "500 : invalid continuation byte") I remove other package,even reinstall the jupyter notebook,but the error still exist.
I guess there may be some configuration file miss configured,but i don't know which one.
How can i fix this error? Thanks.

The error message in jupyter notebook console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 775, in run
        yielded = self.gen.send(value)
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 101, in get
        get_frontend_exporters=get_frontend_exporters
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in render_template
        return template.render(**ns)
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
        self.environment.handle_exception()
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
        reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends "page.html" %}
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/templates/page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
        {% block header %}
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 115, in block "header"
        {% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 40, in get_frontend_exporters
        for name in get_export_names():
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 122, in get_export_names
        return sorted(entrypoints.get_group_named('nbconvert.exporters'))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/entrypoints.py", line 222, in get_group_named
        for ep in get_group_all(group, path=path):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/entrypoints.py", line 233, in get_group_all
        for config, distro in iter_files_distros(path=path):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/entrypoints.py", line 199, in iter_files_distros
        cp.read([path])
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 697, in read
        self._read(fp, filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1015, in _read
        for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I check the ipynb file, it can open use python utf-8, but i don't know why can't open under the jupyter notebook.

Comment: i am not an expert on this, but it is the `configparser.py` that complains. could the problem be in a config file of jupyter? (i do not even know where to find those, sorry).

Comment: thanks. configparser. py is coming with the python and under the directory of python .  I didn't change it.

Comment: that is not what i meant. the configparser will parse some config file (probably a `*:ini`?) that is somewhere. there might be a problem in that config file.

Comment: Thanks hiro. Your suggestion worked. I found which file configparser.py opened. it's turn out "python3.7/site-packages/tqdm-4.56.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt". I delete the file and the jupyter work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks hiro. Your suggestion worked. I found which file configparser.py opened. it's turn out "python3.7/site-packages/tqdm-4.56.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt". I delete the file and the jupyter work properly.

Comment: strange that a file that is distributed with [`tqdm`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) breaks you install... as long as it works now!